# Pull data between 2 dates in redshift

Tags: date, unix, amazon-redshift

I am trying to pull data from Redshift but cannot seem to make the date range work and I am constantly getting an error.

The column where the data is located is called "impression_time" in the impression_db table.

The date is in UNIX

Here is the query I am trying to pull:

```
SELECT 
split_part((timestamp '1970-01-01'::date + impression_time * interval '1 second'), ' ',1) AS impression_time ,
FROM impression_db
WHERE impression_time >= '2021-09-01'
AND impression_time < '2021-10-01'
```

Comment: Your query seems okay and should be working with unix timestamp, please add example data against which you're running this query. If you're getting any error, please add it too

Answer (score 0):

It would really be helpful if you posted the error message but here's what I postulate is happening.

I assume that the impression_time data type is a date or a timestamp based on the WHERE clause (could be string but I don't think so).  Your are comparing impression_time to a string that looks like a date and relying on implicit casting to convert these for you.

With that assumption I see that you are multiplying impression_time by the time interval '1 second'.  This multiplication only makes sense if impression_time is a numeric value.  I expect that an implicit cast is again needed to convert impression_time to an epoch representation so that this multiplication can be done.  Then you are taking this epoch time interval and adding it to the Unix base time, casting that to a timestamp, and then implicitly casting that to a string.  Lastly you perform split_part on this string to get the date portion.  All of this could be replaced by

```
impression_time::date::text AS impression_time
```

or am I misreading what you are doing?

Now as for what your error likely is - I suspect one of the many implicit castings is not happening or happening in a way that doesn't make sense to the rest of the query.  The exact error message should point to where the issue is occurring.